# searching boost::multi_index by sequence and obtaining the next element by order

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I want to search a boost::multi_index container by sequence and obtain the next element by order.

The code below stores four floatswith different indexes (sequence and ordered).

The last if statement is the problem. I don't know how to edit to get the next element by order.

Here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef multi_index_container <
    float
  , indexed_by<
        sequenced<>
      , ordered_non_unique<identity<float>>
    >
> Floats;

int main() {
    Floats floats;

    auto & sequence=floats.get<0>();
    auto & order=floats.get<1>();

    order.insert(0.3);
    sequence.push_back(0.1);
    sequence.push_back(0.9);
    order.insert(0.6);

    // 0.1 0.3 0.6 0.9
    for (auto i=order.begin(),j=order.end(); i!=j; ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
    // 0.3 0.1 0.9 0.6
    for (auto i=sequence.begin(),j=sequenceend(); i!=j; ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }

    auto i = order.find(0.3);
    if (i!=order.end()) {
        // get the next element by order, 0.6 in this case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto j=++(floats.project<1>(i));
```

Comment: By the way, your names are kind of confusing: `sequence` looks like a better name for index #0, and `order` for index #1. I'm not entirely sure if you want to project to index #0 (if it's #1 indeed then you don't need any projection, `sequence` is already #1).

Comment: Is it possible to get the number of position wich j is pointing to?

Comment: If you meen the position of the element `j`is pointing to (as opposed to the number of the index `j` belongs in), take a look at ranked indices: http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnk_indices

Comment: As per your edition, `project` is really not needed: `++i` will simply do.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the `project<N>` function for multi_index iterators. Documentation is here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection

so you would write something like:

```
auto iorder = project<0>(i);
```